# Override @Autowired property annotation with XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, xml-configuration

I've a class `EntityLoader` that's used to fetch some data from a MySQL database using Hibernate. But now the need is to fetch data from two different databases (MySQL and Oracle in this case). So I want to have two beans of `EntityLoader` but injecting a different `SessionFactory` in each one.

`EntityLoader` is defined as follows:

```
package com.demo

@Component
public class EntityLoader {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /* Code ... */

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }   
}
```

And the context configuration is:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo" />
<bean id="mysqlSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
```

So far it works fine. Over this I have done the following changes:

- Exclude `EntityLoader` from `component-scan` in order to avoid the auto creation of a EntityLoader
- Add `mysqlSessionFactory` and `oracleSessionFactory` bean definitions
- Add `mysqlEntityRepoLoader` and `oracleEntityRepoLoader` bean definitions

Note that in `mysqlEntityRepoLoader` and `oracleEntityRepoLoader` I've added the attribute `autowired="no"` hoping that this would
tell Spring to not autowire the `SessionFactory` and use the defined ref instead.

The resulting configuration is:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.demo">
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.demo.EntityLoader"/>
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="mysqlSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- ... config ... -->
</bean>
<bean id="oracleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!-- ... config ... -->
</bean>

<bean id="mysqlEntityRepoLoader" class="com.dome.imserso.api.core.data.EntityRepoLoader" autowire="no">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="oracleEntityRepoLoader" class="com.dome.imserso.api.core.data.EntityRepoLoader" autowire="no">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="oracleSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

But it seems that Spring is trying first to autowire the `SessionFactory` in any case. I get the following error:

> No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] is defined: 
>   expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   mysqlSessionFactory,oracleSessionFactory

If I remove the `@Autowired` all works fine. But I would like to maintain it, as this code is part of a generic lib used for other apps where the usual case is to load only from one database.

Is there any way to accomplish it without removing the annotation?

Comment: You can create a dummy bean named `sessionFactory`...

Comment: Just remove the `@Component` annotation from your `EntityLoader`? You are manually creating the instances in XML (so no `@Component` necessary), and you are manually wiring in the session factory by calling the `setSessionFactory` method (so no `@Autowired` necessary).

Comment: If I remove the annotations then I'll need to configure this bean in XML in all the other apps that uses it. My intention is precisely to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to modify your lib which contains EntityLoader, following these 2 step will do the trip :

1. In `EntityLoader` make your `@Autowired` optional:

   @Autowired(required=false)
2. In XML configuration, exclude mysqlSessionFactory and oracleSessionFactory beans from autowire candidates, add `autowire-candidate="false"` to each sessionFactory:

```html
<bean id="mysqlSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" autowire-candidate="false">
    <!-- ... config ... -->
</bean>
<bean id="oracleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" autowire-candidate="false">
    <!-- ... config ... -->
</bean>
```

Voilà!

Comment: Thanks! You are right! The key is `autowire-candidate = "false"`

Answer (score 0):

It's the component-scan that's causing problems.  Your beans are already manually created, but Spring is trying to create *another* `EntityLoader` because the component scan is picking up your `@Component` annotation.

You can tell the component scan (for just your app) to ignore that class:

```
<context:component-scan ...>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="com\.demo\.EntityLoader" type="regex" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: I'm already using the `exclude-filter` in `component-scan`. In any case, if I remove `@Component` but keep `@Autowired`, the problem persists.

Comment: I think the problem is that spring autowires the property ignoring my xml configuration. As if the annotation has precedence over the xml.